# How to Download all images(.jpg) files from a aws s3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to download the images stored in a aws s3 folder inside a bucket and display the images in my frontend. Problem is I am able to download 1 image at a time. I want to download all the images at one go and then display in my react UI.I am using Springboot in my backend. Below is my code.

```
 public byte[] downloadUserProfileImage(int userProfileId) {
    String path = String.format("%s/%s",
            BucketName.PROFILE_IMAGE.getBucketName(),
            userProfileId);
    String filename = "profile_image.jpg";
    return fileStore.download(path, filename);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Springboot with aws. But in python I have done this so in Java/springboot the syntax will only change.
You need to loop through all the files in S3, get the keys for these files and there is a function of s3.download_file(...).
To loop through the files use a Paginator - [Check the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-pagination.html).

Comment: Thanks . I can do that, but the the aws sdk is new to me. In the code above byte[] return type can be reproduced as image directly in the UI. But for a single image only. Looking for ways to send out a List of image files through some aws object